# What's the difference let f:F = f` and `let f = <F>f`

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface F {
    (): string;
    a(): number;
}

function f() {
    return '3';
}

f['a'] = function () {
    return 3;
};
```

Then I want to assign a function to a variable. I can do it like this:

```
let z = <F>f; // works
```

or like this:

```
let y: F = f; // doesn't work
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense (regardless of the extensive use of `f`). What's the point of the `f['a'] = ...`? Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry, updated

Comment: @NitzanTomer, I'm trying to define a function type, that has method `a`, like `apply`. But when I tried to do like that `f.a = function()...`, TS reported an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root issue is that `f` is just a function, and you're trying to use it as though it were an instance of an interface. (And I *think* that's fine, it's compatible with the interface, it's just a syntax thing.)

This is fine:

```
let z = <F>f; // works
```

...because it's using a cast to tell TypeScript that although `f` is just a function as far as TypeScript knows, you know better and it's compatible with the interface `F`. Then type inference comes into play and assigns the type `F` to `z` because the right-hand side of the assignment is of type `F`.

But this:

```
let y: F = f; // doesn't work
```

...doesn't work because it's declaring `y` as being type `F`, and then assigning a function to it. The function isn't of type `F`, so the assignment fails.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
interface F {
    (): string;
    a(): number;
}

function f() {
    return '3';
}

let f1 = f as F;
f1.a = function () {
    return 3;
};
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20F%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20a()%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20f()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'3'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20f1%20%3D%20f%20as%20F%3B%0Af1.a%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%203%3B%0A%7D%3B))

Using `as F` is equivalent to `<F>` and it's called [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

---

#### Edit

Yes, you can define `f` to be of type `F` like so:

```
let f3 = function() {
    return "3";
} as F;

f.a = function () {
    return 3;
};
```

Or using an arrow function:

```
let f = (() => {
    return "3";
}) as F;
```

Comment: thanks, so ts doesn't allow `f1.a` before `let f1 = f as F;` because it doesn't know that `f` is of type `F`?

Comment: Right. `f` is of type `() => string` as far as the compiler is concerned. By type asserting it to `F` you tell the compiler that it is of type `F`

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there any way to declare a function of type  `F ` without using a variable?

Comment: Yes, check my revised answer

Comment: just one more question, is this `<F>function() {}` equivalent to `function() {} as F`?

Comment: Yes, that's true. As it's written in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions): "The two samples are equivalent. Using one over the other is mostly a choice of preference; however, when using TypeScript with JSX, only as-style assertions are allowed"